# check sum using golang websockets

Tags: sockets, go, websocket, gorilla

I am using the gorilla websockets package to make a server to handle web-socket connections from clients. I am using the sockets to send a json array of ints. I was wondering if there is a way to verify if all the data got transferred to the client without corruption. Any help would be great, Thanks

Comment: Without adding an explicit checksum, websockets run over TCP which has its own 32-bit checksum. 32-bits is not great but it's better than nothing. If you run websockets over TLS/SSL as you should then you get the benefit of a cryptographic checksum (actually a MAC) on every SSL record. You can safely rely on the SSL checksum.

Comment: @JamesKPolk-So I dont need to add my own

Comment: Not if you use TLS/SSL.

Comment: @JamesKPolk-Thanks.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Isn't TCP checksum only 16 bits? Either way, it wouldn't be safe from deliberate tampering, but you can find research that calculates your chances of random corruption and see if the odds are small enough for what you need.

Comment: @sudo-How Can I add my own?

Comment: @Julia12 Probably the easiest way is to have the sender include the SHA-256 checksum of your data and the server verify that checksum. I don't have the knowledge of Golang specifically to post an answer, but something on this page might be useful: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/

Comment: @sudo-Are you saying I should hash my array and send the hash with the array.Then the client hashes the array and checks if the hash the server provided is equal?

Comment: TLS and SSL are extra work to put in and maintain, and you might consider them overkill if you only need checksumming. But make sure you really only need checksumming. If this is a service released to the public that someone might want to man-in-the-middle attack, you'll want TLS to provide the other things like authentication of the server to the client. And if you're using TLS, consider whether you can just use HTTPS with some library so everything is easy to secure.

Comment: @Julia12 Yes, that's correct